# Does apply_async(retry=False) disable the task level retry

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a task like such

```py
@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=150)
def payout_reconciliation_single_task(self, txn_id):
    try:
        txn = Transaction.objects.filter(pk=txn_id).select_for_update().get()
    except Transaction.DoesNotExist:
        self.retry(throw=False, countdown=10 * 60)
        return
```

Now if I call the task like

```py
payout_reconciliation_single_task.apply_async((123,), countdown=10, retry=False)
```

Will the `self.retry` inside the try-catch block inside the except block in the task still be honored?

Comment: No, if you set retry=False when calling the task using apply_async, the self.retry method inside the except block will not be honored, and the task will not be retried if the transaction with the given ID does not exist.

The retry parameter of the apply_async method controls whether the task should be retried if it fails. If you set retry=False, the task will not be retried even if the task raises an exception or calls the retry method.